# Non-monotonous DTS with igndts flag

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I am working with rtmp streams, and I know for sure, timestamps there wouldn't be monotonous. So, I added lots of flags to make sure, that would'n be a problem, but it still is.

The command I use is:

`ffmpeg -fflags +genpts+igndts+ignidx -rtbufsize 2000M -re -vsync drop -i "rtmp://input" -vsync cfr -async 1 -c copy -f flv "rtmp://output"`

However, despite all this flags, it send me tons of
`[flv @ 0x563303498580] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 52544, current: 26606; changing to 52544. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.`
And also the output stream really looks corrupted.

It also drops the following errors:

`[NULL @ 0x56330347c380] illegal reordering_of_pic_nums_idc 26`

`[NULL @ 0x56330347c380] reference overflow 1275 > 15 or 0 > 15`

`[NULL @ 0x56330347c380] reference count 1 overflow`

`[NULL @ 0x56330347c380] illegal memory management control operation 32`

All I want is just ffmpeg to ignore timestamps and generate new ones for the  output streams. But, however, I did not still reach any success.

I use the latest ffmpeg 3.4, headers are following:

```
 ffmpeg version 3.4-1~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

Comment: In place of fflags, use `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps` and drop `vsync drop`. The other errors appear to be bitstream errors.

Comment: @Mulvya OK, I'll try it, thank you. And what can I read/do about those bitstream errors? I've already searched ffmpeg source in case to understand how does `igndts` works, and all I got is more misunderstanding after that (or I simply do not understand the word 'non-monotonous' right (in math terms)) =)

Comment: `'non-monotonous` --> each new member of sequence is greater than or equal to the last. The `strict` variety doesn't permit equal values.

Comment: @Mulvya I've always thought what you say is monotonous, not *non*-monotonous =) Anyway, it seems to me that the only thing the `igndts` flag is doing is allowing equal dts-s, but not less than the last occurred, what I would expect of it if you understand what I'm saying

Comment: Sorry, I carelessly copy-pasted. Yes, it should be `monotonous` above.

Comment: @Mulvya That did not help, finally. It still substitutes the last timestamp occurred and logs this error

Comment: Check these two commands for DTS messages: `ffmpeg -rtbufsize 2000M -re -i "rtmp://input" -f null -` and `ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -rtbufsize 2000M -re -i "rtmp://input" -f null -`